# Steam transactions

Tags: steam, dota-2

I received an offer for purchase of few of my items on steam. But at the end of the transaction I did not receive the money. How long does it take for the money to get credited to my account? Or what do I do to ensure that I receive my money?

Comment: What do you see if you go to http://steamcommunity.com/market/ and click on the 'My Market History' tab?

Comment: It says "You don't have any history on the Community Market."

Comment: Do you mean through chat, or the Market? If it was a trade through chat, you may have gotten scammed.

Comment: What did the offer say ? Did you recieve something like "Those vitem vs a steam wallet transfer ?"

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you need to provide more detail than this before your question is answerable.

Comment: Yes, exactly it was through chat, the items vs steam wallet transaction. Is there no way to get the money now?

Comment: It sounds to me like you did a trade and got scammed. You can't transfer money through trades on Steam.

Answer (score 2):

If you had not offered to sell any items on Steam Community Market, it is likely that you were scammed. There are various ways to avoid getting scammed.
1. If someone offered you to trade via sending you a link in private chat, check that it is a trusted site. A lot of scammers try to trick people by using fake links such as staemcommunity.com instead of steamcommunity.com and etc.
2. You can't send money via trade. The only way is to give the receiver a wallet code. In that case, make sure the trader gives you the wallet code before sending the item over.
3. In-trade scammers: pretty easy to find out, they switch items just before clicking "Ready to Trade".
4. Impersonating: the scammer will try to imitate a close friend of your's account and ask to lend you an item. If someone asks to lend you an item, just make sure that person is trustable, and not an imitator by taking a close look at his/her profile.

If you had been scammed, you may be able to retrieve your item by:
1. Submit a ticket to Steam. This is the most important step to retrieving your items, because what the scammers do is not detectable by valve unless you tell them it happened. Include all details about the scam.
2. Talk to Steam Rep that you are assigned via email. The representative from Steam will either tell you that the item has been returned or they need more information. It helps if you happen to have a screenshot of your trade or trade history.
Hope I helped :)
Sources:
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=232687419 
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=227686782

Answer (score -1):

If you have (ignoring everything @KimMinseo said) placed the items on the [Community Market](http://steamcommunity.com/market), the credit may not be coming to your account because of:

1. The buyer does not have enough money to buy it. (If it is a buy order)
2. Nobody has bought the item you have listed yet. (All you can do is wait.)
3. Your price is too high. (Meaning nobody will buy it and... You'll have to wait til' the price raises to the amount you've listed it at.)

Other than that: The only thing you can do to get some wallet funds credited to your account is:

## Patience

*(And hope that people have money to spend and are willing to buy it at your price)*